# How to get & replace a value in Rust Vec?

Tags: vector, collections, rust

What I'm looking for is a replace method:

> ```rust
> pub fn replace(&mut self, index: usize, element: T) -> T
> ```
>
> Replaces an element at position index within the vector and returns the existing value.

Calling remove+insert seems wasteful to me.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can emulate this easily on any container that gives you mutable references to its elements using [`std::mem::replace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.replace.html):

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

    let got = std::mem::replace(&mut v[3], 42);

    println!("v = {:?}", v);
    println!("got = {:?}", got);
}
```

([Permalink to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f145116db5d80a7cdff04ef6081e2537))

Result:

```
v = [1, 2, 3, 42, 5, 6]
got = 4
```

---

In the case of `Vec`, should you want to replace a range of elements, you would be interested in the method [`splice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.splice), which replaces values, and returns the old one. However, it is likely to be less efficient for a single value.

Comment: Note that if you **don't need the previous value**, you can just assign directly: `v[3] = 42;`. Also note that this will panic if out of bounds.